# Listing many-to-many field in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

my models-

```
class tags(models.Model):
        tag_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
        tname = models.CharField(max_length = 30, unique = True)
        def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s %s' % (str(self.tag_id), self.tname)
        class Meta:
            ordering = ('tag_id',)

class food(models.Model):
    food_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length = 150, unique = True)
    image = models.ImageField(default = 'index.png')
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('tags')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s (%s)' % (str(self.food_id), self.fname, ", ".join(t.tname for t in self.tag.all()))
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('food_id','fname')

class price_list(models.Model):
    price_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    rate = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default = 0)
    h = models.ForeignKey('hotels')
    f = models.ForeignKey('food')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s' % (str(self.price_id), self.h.hname, self.f.fname)
```

I want to query all tags of all food of a given hotel.

I tried doing it like -

```
data['menu'] = list(price_list.objects.filter(h__hotel_id = post['hotel_id']).values('f__fname','f__tag__tname'))
```

but that gave me result like-

```
{"menu": [{"f__tag__tname": "Veg", "f__fname": "Paneer Butter Masala"}, {"f__tag__tname": "Indian", "f__fname": "Paneer Butter Masala"}, {"f__tag__tname": "Continental", "f__fname": "Paneer Butter Masala"}]}
```

and I want my result like-

```
{"menu": [{"f__tag__tname": ["Veg", "Indian", "Continental"], "f__fname": "Paneer Butter Masala"}]}
```

I also tried `prefetch_related` but was unable to get desired output.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I modified my queries like this-

```
data = {}
            data['menu'] = list(price_list.objects.filter(h__hotel_id = post['hotel_id']).values('f__fname'))
            i = 0
            for d in data['menu']:
                data['menu'][i]['tag_list'] = list(food.objects.filter(food_id = d['f__food_id']).values('tag__tname')) 
                i = i+1
            return JsonResponse(data)
```

And it gives me output-

```
{"menu": [{"f__fname": "Paneer Butter Masala", "tag_list": [{"tag__tname": "Veg"}, {"tag__tname": "Indian"}, {"tag__tname": "Continental"}]}]}
```

Not that what I wanted but better than previous output. But I think the queries I am doing are very inefficient.

How can I optimize my queries and how can I get my desired output i.e.

```
{"menu": [{"f__tag__tname": ["Veg", "Indian", "Continental"], "f__fname": "Paneer Butter Masala"}]}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (made to put as a property on your model):

```
def get_tnames_fnames(self):
    return map(str, self.f.all().values('fname', 'tag__tname', flat=True))
```

Also, I would make the first letter of your models capitalized. For example,

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    . . .

class Food(models.Model):
    . . .

class PriceList(models.Model):
    . . .
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am unable to make it work. Can you please edit and show me where shall I put `get_tnames_fnames` and what query on `price_list` shall I do. BTW it is just for testing so I named my models vaguely. I will correct that as soon as I am done with all queries.